# How can I search and replace a line of text found after a specific line of text

Tags: python

Python beginner here. I'm trying to search for a specific tag inside a .conf file and insert a new value in a child tag:

```
<Dad bob>
        <Child>
                Child mike
                Child ivan
                Child george
        </Child>
</Dad>

<Dad frank>
        <Child>
                Child carlos
        </Child>
</Dad>
```

Say I want to insert a new *Child* just for *Bob*. My code should replace `</Child>` with `Child newchild + "\n" + </Child>` only after finding `<Dad bob>`, then stop. When I run my code a child gets added to both Bob and Frank.

Unfortunately this is all I have so far.

```
with fileinput.FileInput(CONF_FILE, inplace=True, backup='.bak') as file:
    for line in file:
        print(line.replace('</Child>', '\t\t' + newchild + '\n\t</Child>'), end='')
```

I can't figure out how to only replace for bob. I'd appreciate the help.
Cheers!

Comment: show your output

Comment: Your code as-is won't run without importing `fileinput` and defining the `newchild` variable before the for-loop.

Comment: You might want to look into [`beautifulsoup`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/), a library specifically for dealing with HTML/XML syntax. Might make it easier to organize the hierarchy, insert something in the middle, and then spit the modified version back out

Comment: I'm already adding import fileinput. This is my output as it is: 
```
<Dad bob>
        <Child>
                Child mike
                Child ivan
                Child george
                Child newchild
        </Child>
</Dad>

<Dad frank>
        <Child>
                Child carlos
                Child newchild <- I don't want this
        </Child>
</Dad>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

with open("test.conf", "r") as f:
    x = f.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(x, 'lxml')
bobschild = soup.dad.child

for child in bobschild:
    child.replace_with("Child newchild")


s = soup.prettify()
s = str(s)

s = s.replace("<html>","")
s = s.replace("<body>","")
s = s.replace("</body>","")
s = s.replace("</html>","")

t = ""
for line in s.split("\n"):
    l = line[2:] + "\n"
    if re.match(r'^\s*$', l):
        continue
    t += l

print(t)

with open("test.conf", "w") as f:
    f.write(t)
```

It's not perfect, here's the output:

```
<dad bob="">
 <child>
  Child newchild
 </child>
</dad>
<dad frank="">
 <child>
  Child carlos
 </child>
</dad>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the responses! 
While not pretty I ended up using linux `sed` command to replace in between lines `tagOpen` and `tagClose`:

```
MY_FILE = 'file.conf'
LOOKUP = '<Dad bob>'
LOOKUP_CLOSE = '</Dad>'
LOOKUP_CHILD_CLOSE = '</Child>'
CHILD_NAME = 'tony'

tagOpen = 0
tagClose = 0
stop = False

with open(MY_FILE) as myFile:
    for num, line in enumerate(myFile, 1):
        if LOOKUP in line:
            tagOpen = num
            stop = True
        if LOOKUP_CLOSE in line and stop == True:
            tagClose = num
            break

if tagOpen != 0 or tagClose != 0:
    os.system("sed -i \'%s,%ss/%s/\\tChild  %s\\n\\t%s/\' %s" % (str(tagOpen), str(tagClose), LOOKUP_CHILD_CLOSE, CHILD_NAME, LOOKUP_CHILD_CLOSE, MY_FILE))
```